# Traverse through only 1 column in DataGridView using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a datagridview which contains 2 columns. I want to traverse through only 1 of the column. I tried this but it goes through all the cells row by row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in rows.Cells)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Why did you write the inner loop if you don't want it?? ((And why the plural in the 1st loop??))

Comment: For-Eaching the cells will do that to you.  It's just `rows[columnIndex].Value.ToString();`

Comment: @TaW 1)question is written up. 2) I didn't know that I didn't want the inner loop. 3) its just a random variable name.

Comment: @LarsTech yeah I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the DataGridView indexer like this:

```
int yourColumnIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string columnValue = dataGridView1[yourColumnIndex, i].Value.ToString();
}
```

Or iterating over the row collection and get only the column you need:

```
string yourColumnName = string.Empty;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string columnValue = row.Cells[yourColumnName].Value.ToString();
}
```